# How to set a new keys from existing key:value pair of a defaultdict?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, list-comprehension, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict(dict)` values as:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {
  'AL2G22360.t1_Sp': {
    'locus': 'AL2G22360.t1',
    'length': '663', 
    'strain': 'Sp'},
  'AL2G22360.t1_My': {
    'locus': 'AL2G22360.t1',
    'length': '389',
    'strain': 'My'},
  'AL2G22220.t1_My': {
    'locus': 'AL2G22220.t1',
    'length': '865',
    'strain': 'My'},
  'AL2G22220.t1_My': {
    'locus': 'AL2G22220.t1',
    'length': '553',
    'strain': 'My' ........}})
```

Say, I want to change it in a way that the `major key` is `value of variable **locus**`. Since, there is a duplicate for `locus value` (non unique, but some may be unique), I want to have another sub keys `My vs. Sp` from `variable **strain**`. The rest of the data can be as it is.

Expected output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {
  'AL2G22360.t1': {
    'Sp': {
      'keys': 'AL2G22360.t1_Sp',
      'length': '663'},
    'My': {
      'keys': 'AL2G22360.t1_My',
      'length': '389'}},
  'AL2G22220.t1': {
    'My': {
      'keys': 'AL2G22220.t1_My',
      'length': '865'},
    'Sp': {
      'keys': 'AL2G22220.t1_Sp',
      'length': '553'}, .....}})
```

Comment: The 'expected output' was syntactically incorrect.  I guessed at what you meant and edited your question accordingly.  Please verify that I didn't misunderstand you.

Comment: @Alfe: You did it nice. Thanks. My head is hurting about how to go about this problem. Do you have any tips on it?

Comment: I just updated the `variable keys` a little bit to make sure the question was clean. But, the intent of the question remains the same.

Comment: Is it in any way relevant that these are defaultdicts instead of normal dicts?

Comment: Yeah, it is default dict. If the `keys:value` are intact doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like this:

```
result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for k, v in a.items():
  result[v['locus']][v['strain']] = { 'keys': k, 'length': v['length'] }
return result
```

This creates a defaultdict whose values again are defaultdicts whose values are dicts.  (This matches your specified output.)  Then this gets filled in a straight forward manner by iterating through the original and copying all values into the new format.

Comment: Can you provide some explanation, so I can get some understanding of the process? It's just good to learn. Thanks much !

Comment: I added a short description.  You can gain more insight by printing out `result`, `k` and `v` in each iteration.  You might want to use `pprint` to have formatted output.